# How to set cookies in REACT NATIVE with react-native-cookies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cookies, redux, mobx

Github: https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies

I am trying a hit a web URL with a Custom set of cookies like token, organization Id. 
Please elaborate that how can I set cookies. Code:

```
const setCookies = () => { 

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  CookieManager.setFromResponse(
  'https://someweburl.com',
  `auth-token= xxxxxx`)
  .then(res => {
    console.log('CookieManager.setFromResponse =>', res);
  })
 }
 else {
 CookieManager.set({
   isAndroidApp: true,
   'auth-token': '',
   'admin-auth-token': '',
   'X-CLIENT-NAME': 'SALES_APP',
   organisationId: 'paramOrganisationId',
 }).then((res) => {
   console.log('CookieManager.set =>', res);
 });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with you having already configured the code?